# Remove shape from UIView to create transparency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Here's a sample view I have right now:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to take a "chunk" out of the top, so any views underneath are now visible through that removed area (e.g. transparency).

[image]

I've tried creating a path, and then using `CGContextClip` to attempt a clip, but it doesn't seem to be clipping the shape like intended.  Any ideas of how to do this, or even if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically to do something like this, one would make a UIView with a transparent background color, and then draw the "background" manually through CoreGraphics. For instance, to make a view that is essentially a circle with a black background, you could do something like this in the `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillElipseInRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

For something more complicated than a simple circle, you should use `CGContextBeginPath()` in conjunction with the `CGContextMoveToPoint()` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint()` functions. This will allow you to make a transparent view with any opaque shape that you want for a background.

EDIT: To clip a background image to a certain path, you could do something like this:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGImageRef image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"] CGImage];
CGContextBeginPath(context);
// add your shape to the path
CGContextClipToPath(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, image);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Obviously for repeating patterns you could use more than one call to `CGContextDrawImage`, but this is basically what needs to be done. Like I said above, you could use basic line drawing functions to add lines, rectangles, circles, and anything else to your path.

Comment: See, the problem is that it's not just a simple shape. This is a dynamic `UIView` that I'm setting the `backgroundColor` property on (with a pattern image).  So, I can't just statically draw the image in my `drawRect:` function in my `UIView` subclass.

Comment: You will have to draw the background image manually using clipping. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to avoid that because it's quite a bit harder to manage.  Oh well, looks like it's the only way.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [UIColor clearColor] in you V to make it transparent, you will probably have to set the view opaque to NO as well.